# How to mark a failed item on a todo list in markdown?

Tags: markdown

I use markdown for my notes and todo lists (e.g. in boostnote) and I'm using the below code to do the check-boxes for the ToDos

```
- [ ] unchecked item 
- [x] checked item
```

**Is there a way to mark an item as not checked but irrelevant/failed?**

*e.g. the goal is not achieved but it's not needed anymore.

Just not checking could mean it was just forgotten, checking it implies it was done, and deleting it looks like it was never considered.*

Currently I use this solution

```
- [ ] ~~failed item~~
```

but it's a little cumbersome since it requires to add characters before and after the item. And the status of the item is less obvious in raw/code view.

Is there something like this? That renders the item crossed or grayed  out. I couldn't find anything.

```
- [-] failed item
```

Comment: `~~failed item~~` is exactly the sort of solution I would expect. In fact, I was about to recommend it until I saw that you were already aware of it.

Comment: I mean it works, but it would be nice if there was a way where I just can go through the list and quickly mark/check the items (without editing the actual text of the item)

Comment: I'm not aware of any such feature. But then checkmark lists are non-standard Markdown so each implementation is free to implement whatever behavior they want. Perhaps something like that exists, but I've never seen it. Besides, tool/library recommendations are off-topic here.